# Как получить доступ к параметру Cell?

Tags: c#, winforms

Приветствую. На форме есть `TableLayoutPanel`, в ячейках находятся кнопки. У кнопки в свойствах есть поле `Cell`, определяющее ее строку и столбец в `tableLayout`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я не могу найти, как обратиться к этому `Cell` из кода? Я хочу динамически менять строку/столбец элемента.

Comment: Смотрите методы `SetCellPosition`, `GetCellPosition`, `SetRow`, `GetRow`, `SetColumn`, `GetColumn`.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, при помощи метода `setCellPosition`.

Comment: Оформите ответом, пожалуйста, с примером кода.

Comment: @andreycha оформил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы изменить позицию элемента(кнопка, надпись или любой другой) в `tableLayoutPanel`, можно воспользоваться методом `SetCellPosition`:

```
tablelayoutpanel1.SetCellPosition(element, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(column, row));
```

Следует упомянуть, что в одной ячейке таблицы может находится только один элемент, при попытке поместить объект в уже занятую ячейку, произойдет сдвиг ячеек.